# What was the first Intel x86 processor with "Base + Index * Scale + Displacement" addressing mode?

Tags: intel, x86

As the title says, what's the first x86 processor from Intel that supports the following addressing mode?

```
mov %reg, 8(base, index, 4)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

where the content of `%reg` will be stored to the address `base + 4*index + 8` (both `base` and `index` are registers).

I only know that 8086 doesn't support this and 80586 supports this. I'm guessing it's 80386 because it's the first 32-bit x86 Intel CPU?

Comment: Downvote button says "This question does not show any research effort" so that's what I'm clicking. Stack Exchange is not supposed to be the first stop.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This addressing mode was introduced with the first 32-bit x86 processor, i.e. the 80386.

Ref: [80386 Programmer's reference manual](http://bitsavers.org/components/intel/80386/230985-001_80386_Programmers_Reference_Manual_1986.pdf) sec 2.5.3.2.